# Pandas copying slices killing jupyter kernel

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have an issue within the for loop of this python code. I think it is due to the method of copying and writing to a data frame. There is no actual error message but my jupyter notebook comes up with "dead kernel".

Is there another solution to this problem? I am trying to go through every single element of a pandas data frame and remove all chars except the last character of the stored strings.

ie, the string helloworld would become d.

```py
for i in range(len(categories)):
    for j in range(len(categories.columns)):
        categories.iloc[i,j] = categories.iloc[i,j][-1:]
```

the output from categories.head() looks like

```
0   related request offer   aid_related medical_help    medical_products    search_and_rescue   security    military    child_alone ... aid_centers other_infrastructure    weather_related floods  storm   fire    earthquake  cold    other_weather   direct_report
1   related-1   request-0   offer-0 aid_related-1   medical_help-0  medical_products-0  search_and_rescue-0 security-0  military-0  child_alone-0   ... aid_centers-0   other_infrastructure-0  weather_related-1   floods-0    storm-1 fire-0  earthquake-0    cold-0  other_weather-0 direct_report-0
2   related-1   request-0   offer-0 aid_related-0   medical_help-0  medical_products-0  search_and_rescue-0 security-0  military-0  child_alone-0   ... aid_centers-0   other_infrastructure-0  weather_related-0   floods-0    storm-0 fire-0  earthquake-0    cold-0  other_weather-0 direct_report-0
3   related-1   request-1   offer-0 aid_related-1   medical_help-0  medical_products-1  search_and_rescue-0 security-0  military-0  child_alone-0   ... aid_centers-0   other_infrastructure-0  weather_related-0   floods-0    storm-0 fire-0  earthquake-0    cold-0  other_weather-0 direct_report-0
4   related-1   request-0   offer-0 aid_related-0   medical_help-0  medical_products-0  search_and_rescue-0 security-0  military-0  child_alone-0   ... aid_centers-0   other_infrastructure-0  weather_related-0   floods-0    storm-0 fire-0  earthquake-0    cold-0  other_weather-0 direct_report-0
```

Comment: What are you trying to do. Is each of your column a list of values? Can you share your dataframe (categories) ?

Comment: Ive added the output from .head() does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the columns have string dtypes, you can do the following:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str[-1]
```

or

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x[-1])
```